# libgdx blender model is not rendered correct

Tags: model, libgdx, blender

I am facing some rendering issues. Trying to build a 2d platform game, my plan is to create the actor with blender. I am new to both, blender and libgdx, and dont know where the error is.

In Blender, the actor looks fine. rendered by libgdx I see only odd forms, not at all looking like my actor.

----- EDIT
ok, I narrowed down the issue. In blender I created a simple cube. This cube is rendered fine in my libgdx app, if I render only the cube and nothing else.
The problem occurs, If I render my other (2d) elements before and I think I do something wrong there.

Maybe, because I have 2 cameras? A PerspectiveCamera for the cube, an OrthographicCamera for the rest..

The cube is rendered here:

@Override
    public void render () {
        //System.out.println("render");
        if (loading && assets.update())
            doneLoading();
        camController.update();

```
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(instances, environment);
    modelBatch.end();
}
```

My Main class has a render method as well. And from there the cube render is called:

```
 @Override
   public void render() {
       this.handleInput();
       //this.handleContacts();
       this.moveCamera();

       GL10 gl = Gdx.graphics.getGL10();

       // Camera --------------------- /
       gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
       gl.glViewport((int) glViewport.x, (int) glViewport.y,
                     (int) glViewport.width, (int) glViewport.height);


       //tiledMapCam.zoom = 1f;
       tiledMapCam.update();
       tiledMapCam.apply(gl);

    // background      
       tileRenderer.setView(tiledMapCam);
       tileRenderer.render();


      batch.setProjectionMatrix(tiledMapCam.combined);

      batch.begin();

      for (Ball b : balls)
          b.render();
      for (Rock r : rocks)
          r.render();
      player.render();

      spieler3d.render();
      batch.end();



      // Box2d
      physics.step();
      updateObjects();      
      physics.debugRenderer.render(physics.world, tiledMapCam.combined);      
   }
```

----- END EDIT

I tried to adapt a sample from libgdx for rendering the actor. This is in class Spieler3d.

```
public class Spieler3d implements IObject {
AssetManager assets;
PerspectiveCamera camera;
ModelInstance instance;
ModelBatch modelBatch;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

@Override
public void create() {
    camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.position.set(1,1,1);
    camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
    camera.near = 1;
    camera.far = 100;
    camera.update();
    assets = new AssetManager();
    assets.load("models/person_animated.g3dj", Model.class);
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    // assets.getLogger().setLevel(Logger.DEBUG);
}

private void doneLoading() {
    instance = new ModelInstance(assets.get("models/person_animated.g3dj",
            Model.class));
}

float counter;

@Override
public void render() {
    if ((instance != null)
            && ((counter += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()) >= 1f)) {
        counter = 0f;
        instance = null;
        assets.unload("models/person_animated.g3dj");
        assets.load("models/person_animated.g3dj", Model.class);
        assets.finishLoading();
    }

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    if (assets.update()) {
        doneLoading();
    }

    if (instance != null) {
        modelBatch.begin(camera);
        modelBatch.render(instance);
        modelBatch.end();

    }
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    assets.dispose();
    modelBatch.dispose();
    spriteBatch.dispose();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void setPosition(float x2, float y2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public float getWidth() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public float getHeight() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public float getX() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public float getY() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're parsing the model when before creating the instance of it.

```
JsonModelLoader loader = new JsonModelLoader();
model = new Model(loader.parseModel(Gdx.files.internal("models/person_animated.g3dj", null));
instance = new ModelInstance(model);
```

Source:
http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2967

Comment: In the samples I looked at, there is not such loader: http://blog.xoppa.com/loading-models-using-libgdx/